# Debug Assertion when using CMFCPropertyGridFileProperty

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm trying to implement a pick-folder option in my MFC Property Grid, using Visual Studio 2015. Like so:

in Properties.h:

```
CMFCPropertyGridCtrl            GridCtrl;
CMFCPropertyGridFileProperty    VideoFolder;
```

in Properties.cpp:

```
Properties::Properties() : VideoFolder(L"Folder",L"C:\\Users\\")    
{...}

int Properties::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
[...]
GridCtrl.Create(WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, Rect, this, NULL);
GridCtrl.AddProperty(ICANDI);
ICANDI->AddSubItem(&VideoFolder);
}
```

Now, compilation is successful and the item shows up in the Property Grid as meant to. But when I click the button on the item to pick a folder in a separate dialog, I get a runtime error saying "Debug Assertion Failed!" indicating a problem with mfc140ud.dll.

[image]

Funny thing is: This is working in Visual Studio 2008, looking at the code samples from Visual Studio 2008 Feature Pack. There's a sample called NewControls which calls the same routine and it runs without crashing.

Comment: It might help to show the assertion.....

Comment: *"Press Retry to debug the application"* - That'll take you right to the expression that failed. That's a good starting point for your analysis. This information should be in your question, too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Assertion problem, and found a solution that worked for me:

- My Visual studio Solution Project was a Dialog project, and I was using the CWinApp class.
- if you want to use a folder picker (CShellManager::BrowseForFolder())
  then you have to change the CWinApp class to CWinAppEx instead.